# HERE maps Turn by turn navigation text in android

Tags: android, navigation, maps, here-api

This rest end point of HERE (https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) returns response including the maneuver instruction in either text or html format. This is missing incase of android premium SDK. Maneuver object doesn't have instruction text with it. Should I create my own sentence from the Turn enum value and Action of maneuver? or Is there any way to get instruction text from android itself?

I'm concerned to create my own sentences since the documentation page(https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/dev_guide/topics/routing-starter.html) of android sdk says

Applications can provide route information to users in two ways:

1. A line rendered on a map that displays a connecting path between all
   waypoints
2. **Turn-by-turn directions in text format**

If this is already existing, I could use that straight away! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is turn instruction text in `Maneuver` object. Get it this way -

```
String nextTurnName = mManeuvers.get(mNextManeuverIndex).getTurn().name();
```

Please note that direction of next turn is in next Maneuver object in list, and distance to next turn is in current Maneuver object.